# How can I get the property 'clip' in css and change it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, clip

I have wrote code like that:

```
    <style>
        *{margin: 0 ; padding: 0;}
        html,body{height:100%}
        div#rect {background: #39c; width:100% ; height:100% ; clip: rect(200px 700px 400px 500px);position: fixed;}
    </style>

   <div id="rect"></div>
```

How can I get the property `'clip'` and change it with javascript?

Just like `$('#rect').css( 'clip', '...' )` with jQuery.

It can not be change by `element.style.clipRight = ''` or `element.style.clip = ''`.

Comment: Are you saying it works with jQuery but you can't set it directly? That seems a bit odd given that jQuery's `.css()` method just does `element.style.clip = ` internally. (Or `element.style["clip"] =`, but it's the same thing.)

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6awK/1/)

Comment: So that's my question.Why jQuery can make it, but with element.style.clip = Or element.style["clip"] I can not make it.

Comment: To expand on @adeneo's fiddle, it works with `.style.clip` - note the position changes after the alert closes: http://jsfiddle.net/t6awK/2/

Comment: I've made a mistake.It is solved.Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById("rect").style.clip